# Formula to calculate projected end time and actual end time

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns:

- Projected End Time
- Actual End Time

**Projected End Time-Actual End Time** gives the difference. E.g.

```
=SUM(K3-J3) -where K3 is Actual End Time and J3 is Projected End Time
```

So, for example,

```
3:50 PM | 3:55 PM - the difference shows as 0:05 - which is correct.
```

But on the other hand,
`3:50 PM | 3:45 PM - the difference shows as 23:55. What I want is the savings, i.e., +0:05 mins`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some tests, you can test if this formula works for you. If you have any issues let me know.

The test table I made is:

[image: test table]

And the formula is:

```
=if(SUM(K3-J3)<0,"+"&TEXT(ABS(SUM(K3-J3)),"h:mm"),TEXT(ABS(SUM(K3-J3)),"h:mm"))
```

So the result look like this:

[image: result]

I basically use an `if` statement to separate the negative results and the positive ones. If the value is negative like in the case of:
`= (3:45: PM - 3:50: PM)` it will take the [absolute value](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093459) of it, and concatenate the “+” symbol with the result of  `= (3:45: PM - 3:50: PM)`. However, to get the right format of the result, I use the [text formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139).

If the number is higher than “0” or “0” then it will use the normal formula, and add the correct format using Text.